# NodeJS Method not allowed

Tags: node.js

```
module.exports.login = function (request, response, next) {
if (request.body.user && request.body.password) {
    response.end('submitted');
} else {
    common.render('login', function (error, file) {
        if (error) {
            next(error);
        } else {
            response.writeHead(200, 'OK', { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            var stream = fs.createReadStream(file);
            stream.pipe(response);
        }
    });
}
};
```

I am using `connect` with `body-parser`. When I first time open this app I see login form - nice, but when I submit a form I see in a console 405 Method not allowed error. I was trying to add some headers but it didn't work. Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you post your express.js route code? Where you setup the URL mappings?

Comment: Also, are you submitting the form via default form behavior or are you making an AJAX request?

Comment: I am not using `express` just `connect`. I am submitting via default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it. The problem was `serve-static` and `serve-index`. It was written some extra headers like allowed methods!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax should be:

```
module.exports = function(request, response, next) {
if (request.body.user && request.body.password) {
    response.end('submitted');
} else {
    common.render('login', function (error, file) {
        if (error) {
            next(error);
        } else {
            response.writeHead(200, 'OK', { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            var stream = fs.createReadStream(file);
            stream.pipe(response);
        }
    });
}
};
```

or

```
function login(request, response, next) {
if (request.body.user && request.body.password) {
    response.end('submitted');
} else {
    common.render('login', function (error, file) {
        if (error) {
            next(error);
        } else {
            response.writeHead(200, 'OK', { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            var stream = fs.createReadStream(file);
            stream.pipe(response);
        }
    });
}
};
module.exports = login;
```